# Center align main content when slidepanel shows

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a jquery plugin called slidepanel and it is working fine. My problem is that when the panel slides out my main content is overlapping it. 
I would like to center the body in what would be the whole window - slidepanel width.

```
Slidepanel.prototype.expand = function() {
    var base = this;
            //set the css properties to animatate

    var panel_options = {};
    var body_options = {};
    panel_options.visible = 'show';
    panel_options[this.options.orientation] = 0;
    body_options[this.options.orientation] = (this.options.orientation == 'top' || this.options.orientation == 'bottom') ? this.$panel.height() : 390;
    //this.$panel.width()
    //if the animation mode is set to push, we move the body in relation to the panel
    //else the panel is overlayed on top of the body
    if(this.options.mode == 'push'){
        //animate the body position in relation to the panel dimensions
        this.$body.css('position', 'absolute').animate(body_options, 250);
    }

    //animate the panel into view
    this.$panel.addClass('loading').animate(panel_options, 250, function() {
        //show the panel's close button
        $('.close', base.$panel).fadeIn(250);
    });
};
```

If you could provide any assistance it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could create a `fiddle` demonstrating your issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/8TEjx/ might be a good starting point because it already has `slidepanel` loaded I'm assuming its the same plugin you are using but could be wrong.

Comment: I haven't got a fiddle account, I should really get one sorted. Basically, I want to know how to change an elements width by subtracting one variables value from the window width. I hope that makes more sense

Comment: You don't even need an account to create a fiddle.. You can code in the fiddle and then when your done just hit update.. Then you can share the link with anyone.  In jQuery you can get the width of the window so like `$('#element1').width($(window).width()-$('#element2').width());` Where `element1's width is getting set.`

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the math lesson. I have updated the fiddle. What I am looking for is for the content div to be centered in what screen space is still available after the slidepanel has been enabled.

Comment: Please share your fiddle link with me.  The link changes when you update it.